# making string comparision in python

Tags: python

I was trying to replicate the strcmp from c in python.I typed the former program and it worked but the latter seems to work as well?please explain the latter one.I only expected == to work but >,< seems to wokrk.How does python know that by <,> i mean the length of string without using len()

```
def strcmp(str1,str2):
    if(len(str1) == len(str2)):
     return 0
    if(len(str1) > len(str2)):
     return 1
    if(len(str1) < len(str2)):
     return -1
print strcmp("ashsih","aapam")
```

vs

```
def strcmp(str1,str2):
    if(str1 == str2):
     return 0
    if(str1 > str2):
     return 1
    if(str1 < str2):
     return -1
print strcmp("ashsih","aapam")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<` , `>` for string operands compare lexicogrphical orders, not their lengths.

```
>>> 'a' < 'b'
True
>>> 'a' > 'b'
False

>>> 'cat' > 'banana'
True
>>> 'cat' < 'banana'
False
```

Upper-case characters are smaller than their lower-case version.

```
>>> 'A' < 'a'
True
>>> 'A' > 'a'
False
```

So, your code does case-sensitive comparison.

---

You can use [`str.casefold`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) for case-insensitive comparsison, (Python 3.3+ only).

```
>>> 'A'.casefold()
'a'
>>> 'A'.casefold() == 'a'.casefold()
True
```

Answer (score 2):

Former one just compares the length of two strings.
But latter one try to find which one is bigger.
For instance:

```
A = "abcdef"
B = "b"
```

len(A) > len(B) will be true
But B > A will be true, because "b" > "a" (which is the first letter of A)